# BrowserSync не обновляет страницу

Tags: browsersync

http://prntscr.com/o4prd1

Скачал сборку галпа. Бруазер синк работает, но как то странно, не обновляет страницу автоматом при сохранении. Не подскажете в чем ошибка?

Comment: Код текстом добавьте